# Are default argument expressions evaluated even when the arguments are provided?

Tags: ruby

I have read that in Ruby, default argument expressions are evaluated for every function call. However, if I have a function like this:

```
def foo(bar=super_heavy_work())
  # ...
end
```

And call it like this:

```
foo "default argument not needed"
```

I have now provided a function argument, so my question is: is the super heavy work function called in this case, or is it skipped since the default value isn't needed?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @DaveNewton: I haven't had the opportunity yet, but I think it's a good question and I couldn't find the answer online, so I posted it.

Comment: It may be worthwhile to use 'memoization' on the `super_heavy_work` method if appropriate

Comment: I can't think of an easier question to answer through experimentation. You're supposed to at least *try* to find an answer yourself before asking questions.

Comment: @meagar: I can think of a million, but even so, so what? I *did* try to find the answer online, and I failed. Now it's possible, because I posted the question on SO.

Comment: @meagar: Experimentation will tell you how the current implementation behaves when faced with the specific experiments you're making. It won't tell you how it is specified to behave or how it will behave in the next version. The world is full of garbage software that worked by accident but fell apart when unspecified behavior changed, byte order changed, an upgrade came around, ... "Just try it" is generally bad advice.

Comment: @muistooshort Yet, the accepted answer below is 6 lines of experimental code with *no* mention of *any* specification to back it up. Not just for this question, but for almost every question I've ever read on this site.

Comment: @meagar: So you're saying that if something is relatively easy for an experienced programmer to find out through experimentation, it should be *impossible* to find the answer online.

Comment: @meagar: People accept bad and incomplete answers all the time. I don't think the accepted answer is very good: no supporting references, no supporting arguments, nothing but "this works because I tried it". Of course, Ruby is pretty poorly specified so a good answer is often impossible. Try that sort of answer in a properly specified language (say C, C++, Java, or even JavaScript) and you'd get publicly ridiculed and down-voted into oblivion.

Comment: @Hubro No, I didn't say that, or anything like it. What are you reading?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, default value expressions are *not* evaluated if you pass an argument:

```
def foo
  puts 'called foo!'
end

def bar(n = foo)
  puts 'called bar!'
end

bar
# => called foo!
# => called bar!

bar("some value")
# => called bar!
```

The same goes for keyword arguments:

```
def foo
  puts 'called foo!'
end

def bar(n: foo)
  puts 'called bar!'
end

bar
# => called foo!
# => called bar!

bar(n: "some value")
# => called bar!
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. I guess the same is true for default values for keyword arguments? `def bar(n: foo)`. I can test it myself later, if you'd rather not.